# Setting a toolbar with Matherial theme

Tags: android, themes, android-toolbar

In my Android application I'd like to set a toolbar instead default action bar. 
I have `Theme.Material.NoActionBar` in my app.

I add toolbar element to my layout and try to set it in the code

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // init toolbar
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

}
```

The problem is that `Activity` class seems does not have `setSupportActionBar`. In tutorials I see that we have to implement `AppCompatActivity`. If I change it in my case I have the exception that AppCompatActivity can work only with `AppCompat` themes. If I apply this theme I need to redo a lot of things.

Is it possible to set custom toolbar with Matherial theme?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use AppCompat and support library, this is the recommanded way to develop Android app, you should never use framework class directly (activity/fragment for example) to make sure you app works with as many device/os version as possible